# What does "-" in the word first-class means?

Tags: hyphens

What does a hyphen signify in "first-class"? I can't seem to understand it.

Comment: Have you searched for "***hyphen usage***"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'First-class' is not a word. It is a compound adjective made up of two words joined by a hyphen. The purpose of the hyphen or hyphens in a compound adjective such a 'first-class' or 'five-year-old' is to signify to the reader that the entire thing is to be considered together as a single idea. This is especially true before a noun. There is potential for misunderstanding in 'red hot iron' that is not present in 'red-hot iron'. Also consider "Springfield has little town charm" and "Springfield has little-town charm".

> Generally, hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun
>   they modify and act as a single idea. This is called a compound
>   adjective. When a compound adjective follows a noun, a hyphen is
>   usually not necessary. However, some established compound adjectives
>   are always hyphenated.

[Compound adjectives](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/adjectives_compound_adjectives.htm)

[Hyphens](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp)